# How to write database migration in sails.js application

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

I tried using https://github.com/building5/sails-db-migrate module for creating migrations but it did not run correctly. Table used to get generated but few columns were missing. 
Is there a better way to create and run migrations? Sorry i am new to sails, recently migrated from Php.

Answer (score 3):

So, it turn out i was stupid to think we need a module to write migration in sails. It turn out on sails lift the application automatically creates the table from attributes of the model.

But on trying that i realized the waterline module which takes care of this does not create for foreign-key constraints as of now.They are still working on it.

If you are using a nosql db then you can use the associations 
http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM

Comment: I am still waiting for foreign-key constraint to get implemented. If you have any update, please notify me.

Answer (score 1):

Time is pass, but nothing changes with sails. Beware use it.
If you already in this trap - try https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-migrations

Comment: Your tone is scaring me. How has your experience been with Sails since this comment? Do you still use it? Would you recommend it?

Answer (score -1):

So people will get a clean and correct answer: The sails ORM (waterline) already supports auto migration, you can change this in the config file (/config/models.js):

```
module.exports.models = {
   migrate: 'alter'
};
```

It accepts the following options:

`safe` - never auto-migrate my database(s). I will do it myself (by hand)

`alter` - auto-migrate, but attempt to keep my existing data (experimental)

`drop` - wipe/drop ALL my data and rebuild models every time I lift Sails

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/model-settings.html

Comment: Yeah I figured that out. All I wanted was foreign key constraint. Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Tried it and just re tried it . it doesn't create the foreign key constraint in database.